# Unable to sign into WSO2 G-Reg Store

Tags: wso2, wso2-governance-registry

I'm attempting to setup a pilot instance of the wso2 Governance Registry (5.1.0). I've installed GREG on a CentOS VM running on my local machine with VMWare Fusion 8. I haven't updated any of the configurations, just unzipped the archive and started the service. Everything seems to be going just fine until I attempt to sign in to either the store or the publisher applications.

I'm able to access the landing page for the apps via the guest's static IP. I attempt to Sign In and once I provide credentials (admin/admin) I'm redirected to an error page stating:

`"Safari can't access localhost:9443/store/acs"`

The http_access_logs provide the following:

`GET /authenticationendpoint/samlsso_notification.do?status=Error+when+processing+the+authentication+request%21&statusMsg=Please+try+login+again.&SAMLResponse=fZJNT8MwDIbv%2FIqQ%2Bz5asQlFaycETJrELmzswC1LvDY0jUuc8vHvybpNQA%2BTokh%2BZft9Ymc2%2F6ot%2BwBPBl3Gk%2BGYM3AKtXFFxl82i8Etn%2BdXM5K1TRvxDNSgI2DLh4yj0lhVdqcrlI2Bxpa1kgU4MLBrbFXvi31V6DfF2ZKohaWjIF3IeDpOJoMkiWeTTEU6EclkmN5MXznbnjnSA0ckcySOzhlvvRMoyZBwsgYSQYn13epJxFTReAyo0PL8CCo6Q88W6GsZLtceFKMH%2By5VgAsmfP%2FzvlwuicCHCM1zi0raEinMRn8p8vPw1kGGlnrhPWpgW2lbuOxDXfZpARo8H%2FUarYAoTj9%2F9B49%2ByzBsTgWFdW4ShZKYLKNd3yfkgde5uG9BQrXJ9p%2Bn578G5%2F%2FQP4D HTTP/1.1" 405 1065 "https://192.168.222.215:9443/store/pages/sso-login" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_11_1) AppleWebKit/601.2.7 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/9.0.1 Safari/601.2.7"`

There are occasional errors in the carbon log but they don't seem to correspond to the login attempt:

`TID: [-1234] [] [2015-11-11 11:33:16,785] ERROR {org.wso2.carbon.identity.sso.saml.servlet.SAMLSSOProviderServlet} -  Failed to retrieve sessionDTO from the cache for key dde85e96-cd14-497e-9f00-c95bf093fd07 {org.wso2.carbon.identity.sso.saml.servlet.SAMLSSOProviderServlet}`

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I recently tried to login to both store and publisher and it worked without any issue. could you check with some other browser?

Comment: Same failure in both safari and chrome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to resolve this by updating the following file:
`$CARBON_HOME/repository/conf/identity/sso-idp-config.xml`

I modified the AssertionConsumerService tags for each of the ServiceProviders in the SSOIdentityProviderConfig. I replaced the localhost with the static IP of the guest VM.

As an example:
`<AssertionConsumerService>https://<guest_ip>:9443/social/acs</AssertionConsumerService>`